# How to draw extended curve?

Tags: curve-fitting, curve, bezier, elliptic-curve, best-fit-curve

My problem is, I have a curve with red dots as the image below. I want to extend the curve like the blue dots in the image. How can I do it?
[image]

I think finding Bézier curve with the red dots and somehow extending the Bézier function may work, but I am not sure about it. Any idea is welcome please!

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a particular program? In a program you are writing yourself? Just finding how you could do this mathematically? Without more context, you will not get useful answers.

Comment: I want to know the mathematics or algorithm or idea to implement this. It can be coded/implemented in any language, it doesn't matter to me. For your information, I am working in Python with OpenCV package. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216369/bezier-extrapolation

Comment: As the linked thread above indicates, you're looking for a minimisation of a 5th degree polynomial. If you're working in python, one way to do this is to use `leastsq` from `scipy.optimize` module for doing the least-squares.

Comment: how do you know you're looking for specifically those blue dots, and not some other blue dots? (i.e.: you're omitting important information about your assumptions that you need to put in your post. If you just want "a continued curve", there are way too many ways to effect that)

Comment: You are correct. Actually, I want to find a shape of something which contains curves like this. I want to extend the curve (red dots to blue dots). There can be many number of extensions can be calculated. From those, I want to select the best which fits most with my given shape. Anyway, I figured out how to get "a continued curve" and it was easy. Thanks everyone!

Comment: in that case please delete your question (or keep it but write your own answer). SO's power is in answered questions, we're all responsible for making sure our questions help future visitors, not just ourselves =)

Comment: Are you asking to delete it because it's too trivial? If so, we can see many trivial questions in SO. If not, can you explain why should it be deleted? Also, how this question will NOT help future visitors? Thanks!

Comment: I'm asking to either delete it, because "you figured it out" and so no one is going to bother writing an answer for it because you already figured it out, or you should write up a detailed answer of your own, and then accept that. But the one thing you should **not** do is go "I found out how to do this" and then leave your question to pollute google searches for people in the future who might come here hoping to find an answer to the same question. That's just intentionally being mean. SO is an invaluable resource for *answers*, not question =)